# Are vacuum expectation values distributions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

In *PCT, Spin, Statistics and all That* (1964) on page 106 the vacuum expectation value is introduced in the following way. The question concerns the highlighted area, that is how can a **tempered distribution** (i.e. an element of $\mathscr S'(\mathbb R^{4n})$) be `of the n four-vectors` (i.e. an element of $\mathscr S(\mathbb R^{4n})$)?

[image]